# Continue app in a smaller window when person leaves app - Android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

How can I create a window for when the person leaves the app they can still use it, but in a small floating window? Very similar to when you leave a face call in Whatsapp.

Comment: check out Picture-in-picture https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into it!